# ShareActionProvider refresh text

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, shareactionprovider

I have an EditText which is initially filled with text from the local db. When the user leaves the screen (onPause), the updated text is stored in the local db. I also have a ShareActionProvider (using ActionBarSherlock).

When the user uses the ShareActionProvider, the old text is send to the target application. How can I refresh the text send through the actionprovider when the user presses the menu-item?

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.share_action_provider, menu);
    MenuItem actionItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share_action_provider_action_bar);
    mActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) actionItem.getActionProvider();
    mActionProvider.setShareIntent(createShareIntent());
}

private Intent createShareIntent() {
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, editText.getText().toString());
    return shareIntent;
}
```

It seems onOptionsItemSelected() is not called when the user presses the menu-item.
So I tried the following onPause(), without luck:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mActionProvider.setShareIntent(createShareIntent());
    // save to db:
    getActivity().saveText(editText.getText().toString());
}
```

BTW: This code is all in a Fragment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps a bit overkill, but I got it working by setting the share Intent every time the EditText field is changed. I added a TextWatcher listener:

```
    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
             if(mActionProvider!=null) {
                    mActionProvider.setShareIntent(createShareIntent());
             }
        }
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }});
```

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled across the same issue and I solved by having my share intent as a member variable in my activity. I set it as the share intent in the `ShareActionProvider` in `onCreateOptionsMenu` and then I can update the intent from anywhere in the activity. To avoid having to recreate your intent and having double entries in it, you can put your updates in a `Bundle` and replace the extras in the intent with `Intent.replaceExtras(Bundle extras)`. This worked for me. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

To update the the shareIntent i guess you will have to override [onPrepareOptionsMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onPrepareOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29) too

So in OnPrepareOptionsMenu. OnPrepareOptionsMenu is called everytime just before menu is shown. call setshareintent again

```
mActionProvider.setShareIntent(createShareIntent());
```

Edit:
Try this

```
 private class  MyActionProvider extends ShareActionProvider{

    public MyActionProvider(Context context) {
        super(context);

    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareSubMenu(SubMenu subMenu) {
        setShareIntent(createshareintent());
        super.onPrepareSubMenu(subMenu);
    }

 }
```

And use this class in R.id.menu_item_share_action_provider_action_bar.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but unfortunately that did not work :(

Comment: I tried this, only as a first test I put a Log message inside the onPrepareSubMenu. There is not logging, so it seems it is not passed this method when pressing the ShareActionProvider menu-item.

Comment: Yes I have:
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_item_myshare_action_provider_action_bar"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/action_bar_share_with"
        android:actionProviderClass="com.mydomain.MyActionProvider" />
</menu>

Comment: I can confirm, that using ActionBarSherlock the onPrepareSubMenu() method is never called.